# What is the best practice for distributing a component that is used by .NET 3.5 and 4.0 applications?

Tags: .net, build, nuget

I have a component that I need to make available for both 3.5 and 4.0 .NET applications.  Here are the facts:

1. Component is used by both 3.5 and 4.0 .NET applications
2. Component is distributed as a Nuget package
3. Component has a dependency on System.Threading.dll (when targeting 3.5, the backport is referenced; when targeting 4.0, the framework assembly is indirectly referenced)

There are several approaches I can think of:

1. Build against 3.5 **only** and ILMerge (/internalize) System.Threading.dll
2. Build against 3.5 **and** 4.0: create separate .csproj files for 3.5 and 4.0 build configurations. The Nuget package will contain both sets of assemblies.
3. Build against 3.5 **and** 4.0: reuse the .csproj files and create new project configurations to build against 3.5 and 4.0 by adding conditional tasks to the .csproj files.  The Nuget package will contain both sets of assemblies.

Options 2 and 3 just differ in how the assemblies are produced since distribution is the same.  I used option 3 once in the past and it didn't work too well because it didn't play nicely with the Visual Studio project editor.

I would like to know if there is a best practice for the scenario I described or pros and cons of each approach.

**Note to moderators**: I understand that this is a somewhat subjective question, please feel free to edit it to make it more objective.  But, please, don't lock/delete it as I really need to get advice on this.

Comment: This all sounds rather unhealthy.  You are not allowed to reference System.Threading.dll yourself.  It is a shim assembly that doesn't contain any code.  Just [TypeForwardedTo] attributes to move the types to another assembly.  Your plan could cause a lot of very hard to diagnose problems for the client programmer.

Comment: I clarified.  .NET 4.0 does not reference System.Threading.dll directly.  .NET 3.5 references the backport (same thing that ships with Rx).

Answer (score 0):

I would compile against both frameworks, and distribute a NuGet package containing both Net35 and Net40 directories.  I would then add a dependency to the System.Threading.Tasks NuGet package (http://www.nuget.org/packages/System.Threading.Tasks).  This is best practice because it ensures your local packages directory has everything needed for any version of the framework.